# How to get customers that have not placed orders in a period of time using two different tables

Tags: sql

I want a list of customers that have not placed an order in a certain date period on two different tables

I tried this:But is bring back nothing

```
SELECT  "OEORDH"."CUSTOMER","OEORDH"."BILNAME","OEORDH"."ORDDATE"
FROM "SAMINC"."dbo"."OEORDH"
inner JOIN "SAMINC"."dbo"."ARCUS"on "ARCUS"."IDCUST" = "OEORDH"."CUSTOMER" 
where "OEORDH"."ORDDATE" is null
ORDER BY "ARCUS"."IDCUST"
```

Please help

I expect the output to show me all customers that have not place orders.

Comment: Which DB is this? And could you please add some sample data for both tables?

Comment: Create a calendar table with all dates of interest. OUTER JOIN.

Comment: What date period?

Comment: @ramaitemphahlele is `idcust` of same type as `customer`? Also do you have any `orddate` as `null` or did you meant `where orddate is not null`?